# sonar-runner getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.picocontainer.Startable

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I upgraded my test Sonar server to 5.2 and am using sonar-runner-2.5-RC1 and haven't had any issues running sonar-runner to analyze my code. I then upgrade my production Sonar server to 5.2 and ran a production build using the same command line settings and sonar-runner.properties file and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picocontainer/Startable
```

I then ran the build on my 'test' build machine against the production sonar server and it ran correctly.   So it appears to me that there must be some difference on the production build machine that is impacting sonar-runner but I can't figure out what the issue might be.

---

All I have in my sonar runner properties file is:

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.modules=svc1, \
  svc2

svc1.sonar.java.binaries=../build/gradle/svc1/classes/
svc1.sonar.projectName=SVC1

svc2.sonar.java.binaries=../build/gradle/svc2/classes/
svc2.sonar.projectName=SVC2

cli.sonar.language=py
cli.sonar.projectName=CLI
```

---

```
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS='-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m' sonar-runner-2.5-RC1/bin/sonar-runner
 -e
 -Dproject.settings=/workspace/build/workspace/sonar-runner.properties
 -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.XXX.XXX.X -Dsonar.projectKey=TEST
 -Dsonar.projectName=TEST-driver -Dsonar.branch=master
 -Dsonar.projectVersion=2.0.0.0 
 -Dsonar.java.libraries=/workspace/build/workspace/jars/*.jar,/workspace/build/workspace/build/gradle/portal/compile/lib/*.jar,/usr/lib64/jvm/java/lib/*.jar'
```

Logs:

```
INFO: Runner configuration file: NONE
INFO: Project configuration file: /workspace/build/workspace/CH-coprhd-controller-master-sonar/coprhd-controller-sonar-runner.properties
INFO: SonarQube Runner 2.5-RC1
INFO: Java 1.7.0_71 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 3.16.6-2-desktop amd64
INFO: SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: User cache: /workspace/build/workspace/CH-coprhd-controller-master-sonar/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=166ms
INFO: User cache: /workspace/build/workspace/CH-coprhd-controller-master-sonar/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Download sonar-issues-density-plugin-1.0.jar
INFO: Download sonar-javascript-plugin-2.8.jar
INFO: Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar
INFO: Download sonar-groovy-plugin-1.3.jar
INFO: Download sonar-build-stability-plugin-1.3.jar
INFO: Download sonar-xml-plugin-1.3.jar
INFO: Download sonar-web-plugin-2.4.jar
INFO: Download sonar-clover-plugin-3.0.jar
INFO: Download sonar-sonargraph-plugin-3.4.2.jar
INFO: Download sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar
INFO: Download sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.1.jar
INFO: Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar
INFO: Download sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar
INFO: Download sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar
INFO: Download sonar-java-plugin-3.7.1.jar
INFO: Download sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.1.jar
INFO: Download sonar-css-plugin-1.5.jar
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picocontainer/Startable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:125)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:37)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.issuesdensity.IssuesDensityPlugin.getExtensions(IssuesDensityPlugin.java:37)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.addBatchExtensions(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:119)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:98)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:275)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:153)
    at org.sonar.runner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:118)
    at org.sonar.runner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
    at org.sonar.runner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.picocontainer.Startable
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 34 more
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 9,469ms last 8 cycles average is 1,183ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 28,431ms last 8 cycles average is 3,553ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 33,431ms last 8 cycles average is 4,178ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 2,661ms last 8 cycles average is 332ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 10,554ms last 8 cycles average is 1,319ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 9,480ms last 8 cycles average is 1,185ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 8,480ms last 8 cycles average is 1,060ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 11,104ms last 8 cycles average is 1,388ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 39,183ms last 8 cycles average is 4,897ms
INFO: [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 4,995ms last 8 cycles average is 624ms
Build timed out (after 180 minutes). Marking the build as aborted.
```

Answer (score 0):

This Issues Density Plugin is not compatible with SQ 5.2 and is no more maintained. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Density+Plugin. Moreover I recommend to open the page Administration > System > Update Center before upgrading SonarQube. It displays the list of incompatible plugins.

Comment: Update center didn't complain about the Issue Density plugin.  I removed it and the unsupported "Build Stability" plugin and now sonar-runner fails this way:
18:23:48 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/squidbridge/commonrules/api/CommonRulesEngine

Comment: sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar
sonar-clover-plugin-3.0.jar
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
sonar-css-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar
sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-groovy-plugin-1.3.jar
sonar-java-plugin-3.7.1.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.8.jar
sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar
sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-sonargraph-plugin-3.4.2.jar
sonar-web-plugin-2.4.jar
sonar-xml-plugin-1.3.jar

Comment: 18:45:49 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/squidbridge/commonrules/api/CommonRulesEngine
18:45:49  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
18:45:49  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
18:45:49  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
18:45:49  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
18:45:49  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
18:45:49  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

Comment: 18:45:49  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
18:45:49  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
18:45:49  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:125)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:37)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)

Comment: 18:45:49  at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptPlugin.getExtensions(JavaScriptPlugin.java:78)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:51)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.addBatchExtensions(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:119)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:98)

Comment: 18:45:49  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:55)
18:45:49  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:45:49  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: 18:45:49  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:45:49  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
18:45:49  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:275) 18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)

Comment: 18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:153)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:118)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.runner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66)
18:45:49 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.squidbridge.commonrules.api.CommonRulesEngine
18:45:49  at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)

Comment: 18:45:49  at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
18:45:49  at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
18:45:49  ... 34 more

Comment: Stackoverflow comment is not the good way to share logs. Please use something like gist.github.com next time. Moreover please share the export of page System Info (top-right button "Download").

Comment: my downloaded System info is here:  https://gist.github.com/a903cbe565e107aca1f4.git

Comment: I also tried removing 1 plugin at a time... and it didn't help.  I still was not able to use sonar-runner from this host.

Comment: Your server env is correct. I successfully analyzed projects with exactly the same plugin versions. Please double-check that your analysis reaches the expected server. If the problem still occurs, then please send the up-to-date sonar-runner logs. And I recommend to not use sonar-runner RC for production usage.

Comment: In this gist (https://gist.github.com/pgraves5/385aa51ce595e18decc7)  the SonarQube access.log shows activity from both the server 168.159.213.205 where sonar-runner is behaving and 192.168.109.8 where it is failing.   Also, access /batch/project.protobug?key=CoprHD:master does not show up as attempted from 192.168.109.8 but from the command line I can run curl and get the same results

Comment: sonar-runner-2.3 also fails - see gist for details (https://gist.github.com/pgraves5/0ba57f2a2d05c23155ca)

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that when SONAR_USER_HOME pointed to the same folder where sonar_runner was executed in, the SonarQube plugins were first downloaded to $SONAR_USER_HOME and then as the analysis started, that location was wiped out for the analysis files for each module to be placed in the same folder.  Ensuring SONAR_USER_HOME was in a different location resolved the issue.